# Convert Binary Data to Download

Tags: javascript, blob

We're attempting to take a binary string and output a download url. The binary itself should behave differently depending upon os and browser.

- On Mac and Safari, the file simply opens an application.
- Mac-Chrome will save the file as a zip, at which point the user must unzip and execute its contents.
- On PC the downloaded file is an executable.

This behavior is determined by the binary itself.

The file, once parsed, will open remote access to the user machine.

Output of raw binary string here:

```
PK\u0003\u0004\u0014\u0000\u0000\b\u0000\u0000\u0017\u0013\u001bU\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0013\u0000\u0000\u0000Connect.990621.app/PK\u0003\u0004\u0014\u0000\u0000\b\u0000\u0000\u0017\u0013\u001bU\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u001c\u0000\u0000\u0000Connect.990621.app/Contents/PK\u0003\u0004\u0014\u0000\u0000\b\u0000\u0000\u0017\u0013\u001bU\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000+\u0000\u0000\u0000Connect.990621.app/Contents/_CodeSignature/PK\u0003\u0004\u0014\u0000\u0000\b\b\u0000\u0017\u0013\u001bU��vɎ\u0002\u0000\u0000l\u000b\u0000\u00008\u0000\u0000\u0000Connect.990621.app/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeResources�V]o�0\u0014}nE\u0016�\u0001:aS�I�\u0004T-�k����mպNi�\u0012\u0017'��\u001b�R~�\u001c��:����aꓯ��s��rR=�\u0004L\u001b\u0011!)\u000fk�\u0001*�\u001a\t]��pP�/���C���[}et\u001b�+��E�JЬ˓����\u0012��Q�\b�F�Ь�i�5��q�B�t\u001f z��x<FN�\\\u001e��\u0012[�GD�CG���\u0005䁧+�\f�'9jף.�ww�C�P����*NM�3;Ɏ>\u0012�c�\u0012�\u0015\u000f�q\u0014q\u0001�s�A8Q��@&��\u001cs\u0004\u0005ဓ\u001ap��H�\u0011\u001fFa���U\u001a�sӗ�\fYK����\u0011\u0017\t\u0011�\u0004��\rA<\n\u0012\t�[A�\t�n���\u0017gKꝫv�<5�$$��bغh�L�e�S�;�M=\u0017�\u0019\u000e�@��a+X b����IY\b5�;n�I@\u0012����V�9��\r#\u0014�m�\u0019�#�~��7��}h\u001f��ܥ�(s���{�E�;�7ː�—x�\\���,�(7��<Ƅ\u000e|X9\u0017�a��r�\\�S�״�U��;{²&�˕\u0014P�Z��&9y�s�5�ϙ�4\u001cϾ:/�%��\u0017@��|�\u0005���G�Ȱ���\u0005y��T6��p*����\u0018���\u001d5�+\u001b\u0016�\u0007f��%��/V�&bDUi�3���J&�۵�\u000e�\u0015�x���\u0018x�(\u0012;��REI�\u000fhh\u0002\td��ۊ!�@��\u001b1?6��;#�3p�\u0017\u001a��A�5\u001c����o�S�N}\u001a���2���\u0006{����=M�[�y�S�+���1+#�3�\u0015�}�g��݀l\u0001<7��\u0014���\u0003PK\u0003\u0004\u0014\u0000\u0000\b\b\u0000\u0017\u0013\u001bU6�_8\u0018\u0002\u0000\u0000�\u0005\u0000\u0000&\u0000\u0000\u0000Connect.990621.app/Contents/Info.plist���n�0\u0014ǯ���\rM\u0017m\u0013M�@�E#)��]M.8Ī��1Ix��ƞl�d�ʇ��;s���i\u001fw~�88RU0)�,\u0007�\u0016�\"�\t\u0013��\u0018����l����{�\u00029g�\u0006��2�x�\u001a#��sN\u0011�#\u001f��\u0006G��@h���u�:����t��V�Xf��@��9U�\n���\u0001`�\u0013˄�x�����X�Fo�gZ͖%�ɖ�\u0007&�=nN.�\r�^heҞ9��3���z���zY��S�\u001e)�yF�~��\t�Ʃ\u0018BWg\u001a��<q�f�Rj�����!z���l�j�k\u001a�y.���\u0003�ʓ�K���$OT��ҭ��)���\u001d�������$�Q�w�E\u0018\u0006C\u0018>��Y�Fљ�p�����Ru\"��7\u0004\r��i��ȓY�xw$�(^�l�( ��\fƜ�\u0014:?:\t�Qȉ�K��^ʩ����04��m\u0017����\u0010\u001f��Cz�}\u0003�H,��c�w]�Y\u0000\u001d��Nz\u001a�H���\u0000o�`Y���t�쾴v�s�\u0011�@IR?AO�b�A��\u0017\u0003��\u0013���-��/�\u0011\t# <j\b\u0002�@��\u001c4�\u0002(ZPu�\t�F�\u0012&v�iͺϾ6m�(�Ph�1�\t�8)�6����d1�M�`\u0017]6���=8\u001b�\u0006PK\u0003\u0004\u0014\u0000\u0000\b\u0000\u0000\u0017\u0013\u001bU\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\"\u0000\u0000\u0000Connect.990621.app/Contents/MacOS/PK\u0003\u0004\u0014\u0000\u0000\b\b\u0000\u0017\u0013\u001bU[Y^��Q\u0000\u0000P�\u0000\u0000.\u0000\u0000\u0000Connect.990621.app/Contents/MacOS/BootStrapper��\t\\S�\u00160~�����\u0012w�  (�h\u0010�Q\u0001QDq\r!\t\u0010\u0005�fQ�R���\u0011�UZ[�R�b[��Z,Z��TQ[Ek�.��CK-u���Ϝ���\\\u0016������}?��̙�̙9g��{�~��\u0013W�\u001182�Ɂa���[ђa�\u0019�鈾R���b��IfJ�Lb�}\u0004���}��\u0012G�g�$~j\u0003�Z�\u0000őm�3����2�A�a����%t$�|Cm�\u0013W�\u0013c�2��`L�7�o�4�o3\u000fg?nT���>Y�*U��5�o�t\"\u001f,��\u000eMڧФ�\r\u001c�^_J<�ׁ�;2�d2M�<�,MeHI�����3Q}\u0007\\l8��`���\u0014�r�\u001e+��\u001b%#�\u0006p�gЇ�3,�ַ/�����7�O�7����V�^_�\u0004����\roZ_�B!Se(TZ�� O��H&�J98_��>c�Bu�R�NO�4`�S\nѷ��7�O�\"K�a�6XߍT_��\ro*^p�}���D�M\r�\u0010��\u001f\bm8���z���j�rQ��kg���9x�q��1������>\u0011\u0007������N>U.�/JKԤʴ\u0006]=})T_9\u0007��s�U��K�`��\r�$c���}/\u0010}n\u001c���Y��*�����'��J���g\u0018\u0007�ߦ���z�x�~\\�8O�W\u0003��i�d\u0015\u000ee��\u000e/��\u0017�M�1��\u001d����T_��\r�qO��S%���3��>/g\u001b�Ԡ&{�p�a�|}��D�\u000e\u000e�\f��7�i�!}�+����g��\u0002�����b�>)\u0007��S�\r�\u0006�m��j9x����\u001aԗ����\u001c�i}�z�\u001dn�o\u0007��m$�>�\u001aƶ�\u001c\u001f=Q\u00121�\u001dC�)o�\rǟ�Y\u0004��t�\u0018�>�\"�XD��I���L\f��\u0016�/\u001e�:\u000b8c`\u0003�\u001d\u001f2L\b�\u0019�0�QN�\u0007C�\u001f�tc��z�_�:я3�v�v����ŷ'�v��I���o{\u000f�Ͷ�ss���/aH�\u000f`��\u001fv=��\u000f�7^��::Xs\u0004�_�\"�A��\u0017�N��u����q�F7_�\u0017�Qh�Il��4�N�F�_\u0018!Y�\u0004s�:a\u000f���\u0018}�\u0006�b�@ߡ���ՉL�rN\u0002\r��#GL�\u001dӔ\u001c���\u001c^��}��b �•k�3\u0012|����Tc5�t�\u0011Q�\u001bk\b.\u000f-'�[N�w\u0010\u0018$h����\b���߾�W��\u001f�D�av�g�24��I��Oq)�])��5�#�<C@=�<�<�<�<�<�<�<�<�<�<�<����<F�{M��j�Ԝ�&�3z�>\\~Hp�TpK�{�w'��n���\u0019�=����f��cU�B\u0019�NXld^�Y�-��XK��i\f�ٝ����\u0012��O\u001c��\u0011J�$��<���Ж'7�4׈J4bX)5\u0007E��lc�4��4���{%�I\u001eH�2\u001f`+=W���Ԍr���1�1'�RG�|�Yˏ\b�\u001c��.fh�^�<�0���\u0002�c��4��Ż/&as̡?A��(��k��|���^��<��u�U~{��gT���C\u0017`fs�(���\u001a2@�z�j��\u0012�'ɳ�\n�\u0017G�:�>*�\b����r�\u001f�ጃD�gw\u0013O~r#�é�_#1�K���)B��@�����ȍ����P:�Bj�^\u0006�\u0013W���3%�i(��\u0005�<�p�9�H��RA�e\u0000j���8y\u001al*�\\y�\u0007�\u0019\u0018��A[\u0005��\u0013=��-\u0002\u001dN�hp��h�H\b\u000e��>�ثS����\t���\"��\u0010��\u001eJ�d6�?\u0003S�V�A\u0011Ġ�SY\u001b��l,�\tA���(��{(������6�\u0013\u0005֚�z�����\u0014�!�j�� �\u001b\n�\u000b�M�\b)�%t��Y�����ؘc\u0012�C�rR��\n�\u00142�ە��\u0019��Tl\u0013����\u0002��\u001c�����\t�:\u0016�Pa��r8hD\u0019��ت������?���;���=J\u0004#�\u001a�������;\u0012�T��\rۇ��\u001c��YЧz$1��D�ye��͛Ml0b@��\u0017�r%ufI\u001d�Y\u0012����s#��\u001fK�J,\f[�\u0013����\r\u0014��\u001c\nw�\u0014^��r$\u0016�\u0003\u0012������:qn\u0014����S|��f\u0011��Z=�X�L�\u0010�\"&��3s\u0018&x�&�\u000e�o'YG�J�湙\u0015\u0010�籋,ީr\b���jOn�U�9ĀDb����\u0001渫��\u001f����~P~h\u0002\u001a�\u0010���\u001e�%��[c\u0006��\fLs\nF�UP��q����-��\u0012�v5�^9e\\\u000bs$7x\u0016�'\u0016v�\u0016z\u001e��AL\u001cFL4`�d�ςɣ��\u0014�̙��N㐵xO�\u001abk\u001f�A$L\u0005��((�����swYN��R<h��k�\u001e\tt�1�F�P�\"�=\u0001�i\u0007$\t��<�\u001dbs���H\u0006�t%d�h�B�ic�Չ7\u0010�HR6j�Ւ\u001b؆RN���/��D��\u0000�wo\u001fc7���\b\u0010�GA,�ĥ�\u001aK�������'P�\u0014\u00151\u0016�D<G\u0006���\u0002�yi�!���P^B l\u000f�� \"�\u0004�Ӝ�\fek✨��\u000b�ف%�\u0012\u0004�\n�\u0006TB��{4�\"%��n\u0012Ȣ0�X'��@r\u001eJ\u0018_�\u0004�;&��J2�#�\u001b��\u001bQ{\u0013�v\u0000��#�,zLRN&\r�\u000b�� ��1\u001f\u000b���Q��\u0005�Es��2d�\u0016N\u0017}\u000eP����\u0015i)#\u0015�!\u0015C �D*f�x�K\u0014v'5*E�\u00158�\u0011_)�%\u0007Q��\u001d���\b�\u0014��U\u0013#�z�#=\u0012�RI�A�|R\u001a.&/\u0003��(��Qx�\u0004�b\u0011��ͫ|�\b��\u0015\bXΠ�\u0016\u0018)3idu\u0014r���8CR� r��\u0004�\u001c)N��|\n�K���\u001c$Nr��DY\n������\u0005��1-�L2q'/�&H��Ġ�r\u0000\u0007#�\u00058\u0015f9+�c!����\u0018�*��`x\u001e�<��H\b?��6�X�\u0006i�����<\"qBjA-^\f��JjA�\u0019�jhD-\u001e�k�Z<\n�x\u0014i��\u0002\u0011�<�\u0000R�<��`mR�´��bR��\u000e�ǋT��lh���Ps/Rs�\"�?+��\u000e1��JF��\u0010i�RF\u001cR\n�F�l!��\u000f�\"57�A�\u0005��l7�\u0001\\����\u0018�+\n��N 0��\n�a�C����4w-4��(l��d��!\u0013�\u0006�A�*\u0001p\u0014Ձ���l�%H�A\u0004= ~\u0004���'c\u001aN�\u0002�\rT�\u001ed�F\u0014�8n��\u001f�*�3�΂~1.�a�Ϣ�-7�(��q&j�<�u3���qSD�a��8\u001b�T�\u0005�\u000f\u0005�1I\u0019�e�T���Jh�³\u000erwn�F\u001a�Ex@���(\u0014�Qȭ�]f��2�g(\u0007B�Dr\u0001�Ev<'�!bŖz\u0011\u000b�=_:<*�.�p��\u0017U�A*��LXH\u0014A�9&�\"F�i܌��<\u0005S:^h�\t����\u0002\u0012��9 L2��I\u0004�'1�Ǝb\u0012�h��\u0016qB\t\u000f=\u0010بv>l���O\u0000tr��:R\tc�m�˪)���a7Q�<�����y�\f\u0018s\u0010��\u0010��CD�\u0011_;�7���k��;\u001e������\t�0�<�\b�\u0012�B\u0018I�\n���LD�\"\u0010VB��C���\u000b��9Q;��-��\u001e�C�\u001eē�'\u0000�\t��\u001e�\t\u0019�\u0017\u0010���<�|�7\t�tp6���\n:���ʜ��\u000e����J_\u0010�AT�\u0000�)�\u000e,ޭI�\u0013\t�U�bbY\n2�N�)�w/R��x�l<��ej\n!�\u0002\u0010U�&�2k�9&)���Y�ɐ\f�8�\n���\u001c1x�4hU\u00148Ϋg٦ĕӀ��t�)�\u0004�t�D�$�HnA���\u0004P��(\u0017�\u0007娓\u0018Q�9���Ń`-\\FV��$(;��(#��\r��#,��%p\u0010�YG\n���#q\u000eZ��y�5���\u0014�Da\u0016���H<���uL�o�`�QWsO/��!7j\u0003��=W�\n��,ٰ�J�+Y�b)c��.��Nay�����VI�\u0003\"��A�\u00002k�:\f/MMl�P��X3�\u0000�+\u000e�\u001f���N��\u0005��82*V?!%\u001d!̡���3��c3l%E�p����\u0016��\u0016���q��D�JRf�}�Z��դ�\u0018�\\=\u000eʜBʌ�/�\u00025yY�y\u000e.;�[v���\u0004�\u0000���̝��\r\u001b�`*�Ĉx{#~�J��mA\u001cY$\\��\u0019��\r\u0004{�Ƴ1��=�\u001a�1\u0010���2�zC����\r{I\t\u001b�ۀ��!a�*\u0001Ʈ\u0012PZb���Z\r)�]���I,\u0002�\u0015`_1i�\u0005�$j\u0007�E(�v�.9,�ՆM\u0014[M\u0014��0R�B\u0014��$��6�\u0001�\u0013ݫq��C��)`e7$�\u0017�\u0003\fŅ�{\u0006��\u0013�\u000b��߱�;e,Yh��W\u0011�F�!�}��eg����bdF�@�35��!��;�����t\u0006O\u0013�$W\u0019�t_a�#��<W��K\u0000?�\u000e�9�NV5^d\f/��{\u001f���S\t�@K`�;�\u0012����`\u001f<?\b`\u0000:(\u001d~��2�\u0017��9n�\u0003Q?!M+Z�\fw[�m\u000f�Z�\u0013��'�\u000eA!h���\u000b�\u001bs���bՉ~\fC/�����w�\f��\\����d�XU�j?�\u001a\u001a\b�1K��\u001e�:\b,h�(ǻɣN�\u0018���+b�\r��s�1��\u0013C�ڵgشX�\u0005p&�F���\u0018�fh6�:��\u0013-�0s��\u001dd!WH�{�8[\u0004�I\u0004,�b\u001b��$��ɰz]\u0016�A�\u0007\u0001\u0010z;AtY\u001d�\\ťu4J\n e�#��:22(@�� 0���ήS�#%�`ߙ�\u0011�sV��L��\u0000�\u0013ؾ\u0017l�\u000bSL���3\u0019D���3����d�\fgw ��S8,��\n\u0014�C�B�aR��p觭���D]�WГ���H\u0007�-�Q���\u001d�z+�x&1�Ⱦz��FS8ؘCV�\u0000��|�\u0007vm\u0011��c�&�+�̰%�4Y���\u0017���&\f�V�\u0001�\t�\u0001RH��T}��\u0006\u001ba��Pw�Z� W\f��B�b�F��F��f4;�(L�\n�\u0012��\u000f���X[\u0000\u0005�\u0016\u0018\u0011c�\u001f��\u0000�}p�mqv\u0014o��\u0018�W�\u001b�\u0010��)�����?\u0006\f\u0011\u0003_���9��z\u000bz\u0003W/���(-\u0006欣���*�[�3\u001ft�!-r�\\!H�\u0016LL\u000b���c5-\u0007��!���4\u001fb��H\u0011�؋��\u0004�f\u0007[���\u0017h�M\f�\u0016�5����\u0015��Ś�X_R�8�\u000e�X!)��]�Bn��>\u0005bN�p$�v��*-1Ok5O��3��\u0019U)�Pn��[����\t�^���t�Մ�\u0015gXk�\u00015Q\u0002�{Z4�t#5�\"֒\u0012\n ����ѣ��8\"��g�|}\t�%\nLr\u000b���� �X���\u001a�\u0005�a9�����`_-\u0011$\u0018�ҵ��-M�B/�\u000e��,�+��ȳ\u000ek5�1\\_���0��\u000fb�V%)��M���`��W�\u0000������Xv\b<�\u0017:@\u001eQ�\u001c\f��\u0011@�����tݔ�\u0002\u0015-N@��B����?&c\b\f�\u0005@9!��@�W`r^1�J��C�GD\u0005�_�2N�C7@Xe�X���:2j$\b�f1\b�?�8o�\u0004#7Gҕ\u00172?�؀�`3*��C\u001ae\u0015����\u000f��\u0013A�\u001b\u0000o�hr�+\u0007_\u0005\u0011\u0003����2�!�#\u001brԱ9*���\fh��$(ܿ!*�&*�G��\u0003���Dux�y<�\f)��Q�C�\b9��$�\u0010T�\u0011��\u001d�$y$�\u000b\nID�q\u000b'\u0018�B\u0015\u00147\u0011_�p��\b\u0013O\u0007(\u0016_w�P��Խ��Q'�!�FLU���W��[���.E\f�y�����6��HU�t���\u0014��\r^V�|��0}*Н�F�|b�N�W@Q�v<�\u0018Ə��>\f��\u0002<�F��S�2�~7��1T370����Cx\u0002�\u0007q�\u0001��\u0006\u0002gJm�r\u000f\f�����'VGVm�Kz\u0004,�&���\u0013�Aq�վpb_-l<B/�\u0010�x_\u0019\u0007y]`\u0013_@y-�-�2\u0001�nE��\b�\u0001\t�y�\u00152RB��\u0019��w�x&�\u0005�Ru�&�GAs���\u0005\u0000��I\u0017߈��l��\u0000�H�σGd�2\u0017�T��o0\u000eC�y�\u0001�VTG\u000e��~\"X\\��\u001d�p��B5\b����#��&;�*� NUm%��BI#��\"�:\u0014=�\u0002\u001e�!�7Y�|\u0011m\u0017k��.���\u001f��=�J�\u000bL\u0010\u0012yx�\u0001뚼�G8u\u0010E\u0005NI�9������b���\u0013\u0002\\8-oP��=�\u0016\u001b��\u001c�S�A��+�\u001f�,���fL,�3\u000b�\n�B\u0016��\u001cG:\u0014\u0000��\u000b\u0018���\u0006���\u0004��@���Dۭq6m�!��_�mav\nhs�t���Hd\u000epd>#2'Ǒu\u001c� ���x��\u0000\u0007��Y\u0001NY�7���;\u0010�\u0005�`b�+���P\u00128�\u001cR�:\u0004r�e�\u0004-;G K2\b� Z�ߒz\u000e�\u0017\u001cc\b\u0017\u0001�\tsq9����\u001al\r�c�(��[������ �r�\b�lf�E���2���K\u0011��9��p�ȡjk'�\u000b��q�N�\u001d1\u0002�g�\u0011p9\u0016{\u001d��x}\u000b�j\u000bv�i?�\u000f#������z�#<���ʭ\u0018\u000f��\tޥwU/��-�E(8};AA�H��\u001co\u000b�\u001c��fK�K���\u0014���\u0010�� S\\�8\fQ���N$b�Km\u0011�J��%�y߉d���e��bŜb��]H�\n\n�\u0011� �\u001a�+j�{\n�X��\u001a*\u001b�\u0007�\"\u001e�=A߁����H�o3\u001d\rяȐ\u0002R'��9��e$�\f����n��Ģb��PH��2\u0002�sK�^\b\u0002��_8\u0011��k�\u0012�h��*\u0019\u000eu\f&�f\f�*)��dBOȰ\u000eU8��3 ��:\u0011\u0017���ZG��\u000e@\u000e�e\u001d������^�k�%]�%}\u0010\b�KF�{���ȼ<\u001f2�HY\u0003NE䞱x�E��r�\u000fn���� ~/\u0002��b�E��Bs�\f]�=n\f��\u0017�.H\u0006��m\n�\u000b\\7�d'�*v\u00059��cH\u0013>��\u0013�\t17\u0002�\u001d����\u0019�6��\u0005����`�tR�l:��\u0004�\u0013\\����\n���\f\u0004$Y�\u001aH[\u000f�`���\u001e�j\u0003 +[H�V�o5�w3�s�\u0005[�J\n��\u001d�?$A�\u000f��\u0002q\u0010\u0015��%�����\u0013C��\u0016c�Y�\u0012kN��\u00051�Ͳ\u0007�·\b�\b(�@h\u001d\u000fѮ\u0017��\b�Ǡ �\u0010��7��v}�:By#\f��\n�\u0011C6\u0019g�N�\u001d\u0005�*\u001fX\u0004W������R���\"k�\u000e��H�\u0017xqZl:a�!�n���\u0011>7\u0000ޭ8\u0016���%�\u001c� ��\u0007���r���n{jɚ�\u0001��)F�5g? \u0018\u0018=<\u000fgz�H&�\u0003�=�1\\\u0003I��\u0015���G���C9�q�I.̸Y�\u000b��\u0017L���h�@�s+��:\b:q�p�0�ƺ�X\u0004Z�\r\u0011Ut~\u0014��J\u001a���\u0016��%�\u000ec/�e���R� \u0010�\u0012f����:�X\u001fj,ڎC[�!5M���ǂ�A\u000b���gH?����\u0004���\u0006\u0006\u0011\u0003��ʺ��>��\b�-1��\u000bm<�\u0002b�A�w�خg�\u0014��lq\u001b��\u0003Ê\u0019k'�� #\\�\r��\u001d�~7j)�\u000eT�=T.(�,f�A�W9\t�R����h\u001d�G��(\u001aȌ��!�\u0013H*��!�q8(soIj\\�Ю��\b�;��]\t�*\u0006\u0000#��5��b�o*��&�\u001e�@*�)����d̞�\u0000mP=\u0002\f\u000f\b��n�G��F�F�6�ή�Z���W�<W��2>'��%\u0010L�`�&��k@tN \u001b��Cl<� \u0005\u0018��l��W>�\u001a\u0015ֶ���ԍh\u00187�h�o$��L{̚&���\u0011�z6hZ\u001dĒ�]h�<bS���e\u001a\u0005Z3�Z\u000f� �\u0019Ґ�w��7��fp�f#ʱ�sut\u000e�s^\u0011��\"�\u001ca��+\u0007�)B@\u0017F�������HN\u0011��su�\"\u0002���nE�2\u0001mX�P,�\u0016\u000f��L\u000b\u0019O@�{'Ҹ4�*X��e\u000f�@b�+\u0003�.��4��bdi��������K���԰E�$��=�\u001f�� ��4xE��-��\u0014�}1\u0014�ڿz\b&��\u0015Rũ}[�B$\r\u0015Re�!E�B���vP�'\u000f��\u0018�����'���R0P~\f��@)�\b��P\u00128�� ˹�\u000f\u0006�t���3\u001b\u001f��&��#�\u0017�Yas�\u001cF�\u0001_j�*�@۸$�\u0006�_�Js�M\u0007\u000fr��\u001c��ƿ\u001f�{;J��=�C5\f�HTE~w��W�SZn�\u001d��L'|�\u0000�u�{PJ~s��Ĭ�2\u001bkr�g\u001d��Ȭ�*��Lu���Y\u0003'�d����\\�S�\u0012\u0007\u001f8�\u001c̉�\u0004\u0019�~���sw�����H��\u000f�\u0004�~\u0019ѯ��\u0004�\u0003��Ⱥ\\\nt\u0017B���7���c0v�ڎ���g\u001e>�E���x�t���y^�@\u0014�U��\u0019��������Hj�,��A\bE@��;��ߝj�߱�\u000b9��ܨs��{K|�G`m��o�8�J'�4D\u0000��*h���Ġ��\u0011��\u0010��ꮪ�\u0011߄��w�P�V��j����~��$[\u001b�\"7W�j\u0001M��m�\u001dl\u001b=&�Bn\u001b���B�\u001eW���\\M(�>>^�@((D�v\u0011M\u001b����$�H�1I9�����a\u0010X�\u0002L��bjq�gVT}����o�\u000f!\t!Nn:��}\u001fBܣ\u0005�q\u0013��1I-�sn�\u001f�T��Z���*� ��CY� ��H��D}�BIlz U\u0018���6�\r����<\u000f8����A\\�ך�vwp�e\u0007|g�{��Z�^��+���z=n���dJsN����V���jsϓ_m��\u0015��9��W�qU쏭(\fk�_d�A�֒�B��8��<`p���@�&q��'��7���ْ�Q�\u0014q�9��W͒Z����]�zǷH��\"�^\u0015B4�Z�%|D����\u0004e9�r�H�{�!\u001eu=��H�;\u0010:\tq�\u0005\\\u0010�\u0006ɾb3�\u0004��c�%(|\u001a�:�\u001b�6c\u000f#c��jo賵����>[���u\u0010�}�\u0006�٫v�����~�\u0011�#\u000em�/��V�w\u0003{Ll+��\u0015kH+�t�\"�����jh�4G��~�\u001f�1���\u0010����\u001a\u001e\u0003��zi���Vr{�yW�K���~H;�\u001bҜd}~H��\u0000�ƿ;�R�o\u000b�T@{�\u0013�l|��H���d�=\u0010gJ�x��UFu�����\u00064�=Y-y�ޗ]�y�\u0012|�J����:sf]\u0015>酰��' \u0002�\u0007\t\u0013Ռ��\u0003�\"��k��\u0016ET�yj���ri/I-y�G�YpTl�'�o���j|�\u0005R�恵z�ª)8h�K���D��Z�'k#<�\u0005�\u0011��n�PSf�U�\u0006�ͽ�j�\u0017��E��(��\u000b�(�\u001b~)\nJ\"�#|�\t�ܗ��c\u0018\r?O��gz\u0000�*Ie��\u000b�3�A8�7�\u0018WY��ź��|P�I\nz�;,=�IAџ����\u001d��3�\u0003\u001e�C?�E�z�\u0005g�zm��\u000b�ߪa�bU:�����y�L?�i�y9_ؘ؞��\u0006l�\u0007�a�|�ɍ��\bs�{:���\u000b)/���\u000e\u0004ڗ����\u0007���#����³`��@�\\���\u000bM4Ÿ�^���x\u001f��q\t�E��}%޻�6sP\u0017�E��\u0003�~|G1���<,������\r?z��!|3�Hp�����\u0014WJnz/�x�@��\u00060�S ���\u001b\u0000�I��j�x�\u0013X�\u0014����!�\u0015�`���J�]\u0003?�f$Q���7��X��\u0001\r\u001e\u001a;\u0006��\u0007�J��z� ڊv\u0010I�/�c�\u0016�+\u001a\u0010��|�����r�\u0006k�=G��6P�{K(\"�\b6��\"��#h_I9�Uq]|\u0010�id\u0000\u001a->�̖�\u0002�����]�\"���\u001dsPwh\u001a�\u001b�w$�m�x\t>r?\u0002���+���7k���G(;��@iX\u0016yN��4G��j�'�)���D6<��\u0010��\u0010\u000em\u0006C\bi\u001b~\u001e\n?�\"�\r��N\"^X��s�E��rĥ�߬��\u000e#^\u0012���8nu6<\u0013F��\u001e�x;�3�'|�?���\u001c6����~͟���� (�Ⱦ�/D�\u0010�Ɵ�\u0000�s���o\"����؞�Y����dS�\r�o{�P%���\u000e��r���\r\u0007�\u000e�˹��e��;\u0011x��\u000f��\u000fw{�V���A:�Z�]�]\u0004_\u0007����\u0007������\u001f\u00025\u0007\u001d\u0014A�\u0002H�\u0006��\u000f�\u0007\"n?hk#,\u0015��%��#\r�Uo�!J �\u0012P�\b���l^a\u0018��!�۶�\b�W�4�:�P�f�n0�������\u001a?Z.���9�\u00167�>��o\u0005��\u0011��\f�����2��\n���*��\u001b����7�o-��\u0005���{��\u0001�}\b���\u0013��\u0005��q��N��\u0005�����\u001a�\u0018��h����8\u001dO҃q:���㴘���t I��i\u001f���]H�#N{��7N;�t+�~p\u0010��8]C��p����q�\u001cI\u000bp���\u001fw@�}$�7N\u0017��]�~�����$�\u0007N�!�j�6��5�6��%�N!�8=����\u0018��\u001e�#H�\fN\u0007\u001f$���#~YL\u0012�\u0014�\u0016�\u00132\u0019�ܠb\f�4��t�J�@�\u001a�NW�\"Pn\bdKR�Z�J9>=V�Ф+��� �\u0019�\"�\u000e%5Z���R������GI7\u001aTT\u0007�JW2��T����LW\u001bR�5Ȉt�~R�Xu*2@�1�\u001b\u0018�*U%׫\u0018��pk\u0012�\u0014��\u001a�Dբ\u0010&U��lHA*\f��F\u0015��Ѥ��^E�B�(k�1-Q��\u0005�ʆ@�!L��\u0010\u000b�{B\u0012U\\\u000e\t�@p\fR\u0017�UQ&Hc\"$���L�G#K2�z����Z\u0004\u0007,j���j�:M�\u001a�NV\u001b�S�:�\u0002�s���(8\bT������Ej},>�\u0012�4)\t��2���Q���('nJ$FY\t��\u0005�J\u000f\n\u0011%D!W��b4�jŢ\u0010�\n���:\u001a* �:5&JeH�(C��\u000b�KUr�J7V�J\u0005b�2vQ�\"E�I�\u0018�SH1!:���KG%OQ鵚t�*D��it!V�B���\u0015\u001a%1O���Bu!�j���9}\b�2����M!y�%��(Ob�A�\u001e�Q\"�����c���T�y\u00001r\u0014\rD͘EaZ-�\u001b%qn�&\r��Žm�\f�\u0001cu����JU\u0006'o����M\u001d\u001bL$9�\b��lUe[��\u001e������,LO��\t�B9r�B��듌�L�j!'֘\u0014�>�\u0013��\u001a�i������t���\u0013[H�ˡ�l�ฦe�~\u0015�O(V����TC�<]��:�B�B]>B�C=K�[\u0014f�\r\u0016��t\u0015�.M�Ts�j�>Dn@�%��̺�mtI�V\u000e�>U��D�\nxD��.\u001aoP�Q�\u0006\r\u0000*)7\"�����\u001bu:�&�5���u:�\"\\�I���\u0010\ba�dc\u001a\u001e2\u0000��\u001bQ�\u0012�TH��U\u001b��\r�T�9\r\f��:\u001d\u000e<D�0\u0018�L\u0012j\u0010�o�e�\\�$%�Б&�@\u001dOT��S����\u000f[qr�\u001d:U�f��SWZI�\u0002֠`��\u0012�:\u0019\u0006[\u0005��\u0014cz�F�e��$y�a�\u0011�/\u0015�3�Gi���D\u0015�ttF��@*huB�ظp�\u0002�n�N�ɸ$�m:>к%�5��g4|�4*B� �Tq���bLNF9*\b\u001a|�x\bG@�\f'!�1�J�P#�t�>�^b�\\��\u0015K�\u0010�g����I:�a\u0015\u0001�@���KF����@&�d�A\u00030�-8�u�d\u0014fX�ll����E!��\u0002\n�\u0014�{F���Ɉ\u0003\u0002q\u000ebdԶ�–\\0$�&\u0011+�  �bj;\f\t0\n��(�A���z�\u00027�\\��'d���\u0004mE\u0001\u0001U���'�ѓQ�i\r��J�\u0012�`a\u001f1�\u001a��$ \b�za�T#C[@��%\f�9�0k,;� $��S\u0003��\b��(�G<Z1>\u00021���C��\nf�d*�U�iS�@��\tz�T|><\u001e��hl\u0011�T��E!B�s\\�x\u0010�\"Ӂ\u0015E\u001c�f��\u0010�\b�\u0017�=QI=�!ž}�=\u0007\t{j�B{\n3��I�S�(�&.�-�yzM:\u0013��g�3֪\"K\"��Ϸ�V��\u0011;5\n�qJja\u0003\u001a�j�i\u001a�\u0002Tp(�Bdl���l�5̖*�%\u000fe�lT+�'\u001acFc7�j0\u0018\u0010k��/�F&�!\u001b��\n$XL�����Y��d�Y9G�m\u0006�z<l�N��BC\r�q~z��0\u0018�:8\t\r��*�`�|2�i�\u001alԥ�\u001aP��1}�l����T�1갸B��7j�\u001a����\u0013i\u0010���O�F��\u0016(ĝ��/\u001b�+G�2�za�\\1\u001f��R��\u0004�-ff�\u0011�a��0[<\b�\u001aSS�Z4�Q\u0016_;*\u001e5�x�\u0012J2����[�W���l\u001fy\u0012�,�)h&K�]G���\u001a���qk���K\n���L\nC�+�t�6EŖ�b0h�!~~(�\u0011\u0018\u001fA\\2\u0006�w0��Sx�h����(��\u001d��;Zc�%\u0004���\u0010!�\u0016oj�n�\u0010\n\u0015��8]jh謾L�9����H�D\\\u000eMG\u0011Fb\u0000� )�bE�j\f�T!^.\n\r���2\u0006���t!Z����E)L�,�C�IM\u0012��4��\u00172t�g���R2�)x��ە�^K}�\nbݯG\u0015F�\u0007\u0014z�^}�~��`��`(\u001c\u000b�\b{��ʌ騉�Ȯt�A��Z\u0012lH�\u0001\u000bQe*[ɋ�ZL��|��q��N�3��|��\u0017���\u0014�3�,\u0004�Rΐ%�\u000e���9��'����\u001e�z�\f��൮p|:껩�(�bla=x0\u001a �_�)\u0004��\u0018�G(ש ~ǄGHƎ���012*zR��)�S�M��1S��@k��\u0014����i�\u001a�\u000b:���`aƢ�\"��!�AC�\u0005\u000f\u001f�g�Bv��g�\b�&(!Y1\n�Գ�٭\u0011�j�����\u001cc`5�����pyz?\u0003��&�\u001c(�\u001b����\u0006\u0012c�t��8�a�����\u0004�h�\u0003_����6\b\u0006ad\u0003B\u0012\u0005\f#��=W��eϤ�l��8v�ϵ�G_\u0005��\u0017j�oܱl���\u000f'��98�\u001e�\n×��90LD=^#��\u0013�\u0011�Rx\\ґaf�\u0014��}|kno��0��3`tr���Ŏ\u001fA�����\u0011\"����{NLR�ى`�D���0�a�$�s�[2n� ��\u0011ˈ�1\u000eB?�;�\u0011\u0014�\u001f#�1\u0002�0�^��d�Ԗ�m�\u0014F��%�j��/ �a[�>%��-a+\u0011���!ܝṁ\u001b#��n�/\u0015}3��\u000f��%��k�o\u001f��P��M��'a˟���v`��\u0004���ۡ�3�'k�\u001c�\u001d�v\u0011�7��\u000e9���ہ�������\u0010O�^h��%�c\u0011�[�\u0004_ ��PL�^i�o6~\u001f\u0003�{�\t�\u0015�����6��4?UP��&��~\u0012�&|_4�O짊/\b��\u000e��a?��\u0012�MM��~z�%�ք>��\u0003�/̱q>짪��/��r��z\b\u0016�DB��n�\u0016��b�m\u0010�U{��N_|��!5�꛰�i����?�\n\u0011\u001b�H�7`OhC�����(��D�=4\u001f��W�\b\"��i���h�\u001f�BR~�����u\u001b�0?��\u000e��/\u0011�F�\u0005�G�gP>a\u0013|�WZʗ�\u0004_*�+{\u0006}\u001b\u0010��2��j��i~����\u001b}7R>qSv�o\u0011�\u000bJ���J�\fM���Ft���m�\u000f��\u0014��M\u0013|��x]'|/7��Ƿ\f�׵\t><�i)ߨF�\u0018�R�e)�3\n�\u0017�[Hߗ���|\n����ӏ��w\u0014FP\u0018C�l\nS(4Ph�p\r�\u001b)|��\"\n�QXF�9\n+)���\u0001�N�=w^\u0014v�Ї�@\n�\u0014FR\u0018Oae�};�q�\u001f��y�g顔޶\u0011���ȧP�g#�\fJo�\b=���\u001b��O���$.�mJ翋������w=žRJ\u000fj�~�����b�\u0012�7�4LL��\u001a�w�7������\t�t�F���M�_(�{4B���΍�S(���\u001b���һ7B����6B���\u00075BwH���\u0011zx��� �����7\u001cK�F��\u001b�7S\u0010��\u0011�\u0000E���S4\u001d?����?�)�\u0014M��H��\u001a���t�F�_>���O)�����{��[7Bo�lz��N�\u001d\u001b�\u000fW6�?R�t���lڿ\tJ��\u0010��jJo�\bݨlz�ZF���7Z��\u0014��)}r#��)ݵ\u0011�me���Ce�����iy_U��;D���\u0012�j��Ѫ���dJ��\bݠjz~�}��5���k�S�g\u001b��k�~Be�\u001eG>�\n�;7Bo��t��Դ������Oj:~G$5=��=��5����[J��\b�Ϥ���:���H����}oe\u0015����-�_Ї~�\u001f��������mξ_�}�q)}��n�����N\u0004\u001e��h�[4?��C�O��:\u0013x��\u001f���N�/��\u0003}H�L2�:\u0005�����h��E!?��vJy��^K\u001an���;�_ho<������|>��h�}��v!p%�_ؕ�u��R��\u0006�/��\t�\b�F�\u000bi~%������w'�\u000b�������R���_H�\t��=��\u001e��L����|\u0017y�J��JJ���d�P��_y�?�g���O<&��OmL��L�L��Y�\u001c��/������\u0001����.^�v*��������sy����;��?\"���k<�1�l~�c���g��\"��N\u0018��\u0001�tw�~\f�+��{�\u001a����\u0007��n<�|J\u001f�\b��\u000b���|�x�ޯ9K��Ϭ_�O6\u000f_�����N3���<�'\u000f���\"\u001e\u001e�����(\u001e>��'��\u0017x�u\u001en��f��<|,\u000f���Y<<����/��;<��,{�\u000f\u000f\u000f��\u0012\u001e\u001e��g�p\u0013��'x�J\u001e�\"O�\u0015\u001e�.\u000f/��y��|{x���\u001f�����~N���xx\u001b\u001e{\u001eޓ�����x�$\u001e>���yx&\u000f_���y�\u001f<��\u001c{�\u001d\u000f���a<|\u0012\u000f���U<\\�óy�k<|\u001b\u000f���_����;<�c�=ޕ�\u000f��y�\\\u001e�����\u001fv=ˮo�\u000f}��~\u001a[7��j/\u001et�Av]!���ҕM�)md���\b���)���ҳ�˧�&<E���l�\u0012�����������ק2`d[/�@,�\u0011��\u001c\u0012\n\u0005�\u0002\u0013��\u000fP�/(u,w.t�u.w)w���t.tM\u0010�\u0004B�I�\u0015�;�\u0004\t�Y\bל�\u001c�q<\u001c-��$G\u0001S�ЈI���\u0015خ�{Yzsp���0��<ƣ\u0005�8�g��:\b�<���b���'�^OmG�M�P���ڟʗ��cx�1<y���8*���Z>{\u001dw\u001e����\u000f�ɳx���\u001a�[<����ñ>%g����U�=�Pа���o:\u0010��y��\u0004��sqhz�v\u001f�gqV>�W.����?Qy\u0016g�\u000by�<y�:�c��(�^/��H�Y�Y㟽�<��W�Cy���l������<�|�<{�z)�������^�~�ʳ����^�.��,�����Y���}<�t�ǃx�t�\u0016��N�x�\u0013��Ǽ�\u0017S{;;���?k�r�?�ʗ��Ky���C��\"�D*�⫝̸�����b}�\u000e���8�S_�\u001e�B�//\u001ex�\u0014���\u0017\u0000�F�Y����_�+�v\u0000I/��,���8��sq��/I�M�Y�*ϳ?�g?�\u0017\u001e����,�ʳ����,~\u0010��mF�g�����\\��.\r�\u0017�'\u001f���t~���S�k�J�?'��f*��V�ڳ�מ��\u0005\f\u000eSy\u0016g�6>'P����)~ɵ��\u0014��\ty�LT>ލ�\u0007Ϟ��7\f��)�ʳ���/��\u000b�<��5\\����\tT޳\u0019m��V\u001f�>�~T��'�œg�f$^��x���N��(^A�\u0018Gk�\u001d���*�\u0017�z�x��=��Y��\t���������Շ�C{��\u0007UT�ş�\u001f��&*_ȓ����\u0018��E�|��?��������ʳ���7�w��-�|“/�ɗ����?�Py\u0016g�6�����Py\u0016������K�cx�x�,�E\u000b������ni����r\u001e����ݲ���QD���t��+ŋ(~\u000b�\u001e\u0002��\b�`�qv�Ӗ����\u001f��������\"���~a%����vV���\u000fQ�]\u001f_e�\u0014w� 8�~�Eqv=\u001a����0���zq%����{\u0014g�s�x��`�G5\u0014g�;m<\tή_�)ή?fQ�]O,�8�>����|_����)����]V?�\u000f�x\u0011{��m\u0010���*���|3���S<���@��S|\u0015����-����\u001e���7�(Ύ?��t<\tmEpv|�P���R����(��ǋ\u0014g�W��\b�_�R��\u001f�(��\u000fa\u0014g�X�wko�\u000f)���}G�)�޷�\u0001���\\��8{��[\u001b���C�R���a:���)2)����\r�\u001dl�s��8���)����R����][����\u0005R���h\u001a�=8�a\u0012���p\u0011�=;ڞ�Ȣ8�<F.���1\n\u0010�(�-�S:���g\u0018\u0017�g81^�\u0016��6��<�\f\u000f���\u001f\u0011�z\u001b���=��۞ߗG���*\u001e��'�\u001a���G/��x�^���\u0000\u001e>���|\u0002\u000f��������%<�<\u000f�����ۗ�Cp�c\u0002#\tn��6����Xg���<�E\u001e���\u0017���<�\u000b\u001e~����+x�_<�y\u0007��\u000e�`_ߐ\u000e��1<�l\u001e��ó\bn�Mz\u0003\u000f����������x�a\u001e~���*\u000f��wC��!`<: �\u0013A\u001c��\u0010��\r�\u0016�|\u0004� X�`_\u0004q��Cp#�}\u0010|�\r�\u001c=J\u0011\u001c�`!�\u00031D|�\u0010��Pܞ@\u0011�\u0007#X�\r�$\u000f���\u001f�E�pMͣ\fA\u0004}P~\u0000�B\u0004�`���y3�2\n��\u0013؁�\u0004\nS(\u0014�J��|\nM\u0014\u0016RXJa%���\u0018\n)\u0014S�@���B\nK)��\u0010�(�S(�0�B\u0013��\u0014�RXI!�Q O���\u0004\nM\u0014\u0016RXJa%�8�A�B1�\t\u0014�(,����J\n�\b\u0000�\u0014�)L��Da!��\u0014VR�#\f�)\u0014S�@���B\nK)��\u0010ߐ\u0001�\u0014�)L��Da!��\u0014VR�o�\u0004y\n�\u0014&Ph����R\n+)�7�<�b\n\u0013(4QXHa)��\u0014�@q9\u001e�\u001f\n\u001fP(lO��B-�E�>\u0001�\n\n�D\u0018�P\u0018Ca\u0006�&/���od�0\u001fᓱ=\u0014\u0016QXJa9��\u0014�R�Պ@!�\"\n�\u0014�P�@��B\u0013��\u0014\u0016RXDa)��\u0014VRXK!~�\u0006ʧPH��B1�1\u0014&P���Da>��\u0014\u0016QXJa9��\u0014�R�Ͻ��)\u0014R(�PLa\f�\t\u0014j)4Q�Oa!�E\u0014�RXNa%��\u0014�\u0007A�|\n�\u0014�(\u0014S\u0018Ca\u0002�Z\nM\u0014�SXHa\u0011��\u0014�SXIa-��A((�B!�\"\n�\u0014�P�@��B\u0013���x\u0019����7\u0004}G��H�\rE�Q�;\u001a}�؋O\u0002��q�\u0015�ߔ&�o$�F\t�~w\u0012�NAߡ��\u001d}���Y@�\u0011�* {� �o\f�J�W������4M�1M\u0005\u0007�H#\"�����E8%�O�������IC~��(?�\tl~\u000b\u0002��3�1m�i�\u001eՉFu��.ۗdM!�\u00076D��\u0005\u000eNǇ!��e\u0004\u000f�\r\r�#fi��� %ħ�ͱb�3N�y��S[VC�6B垉�(\u000b\u001c�4��M\u001a3!\\6~Z�\u0014Yo\u00191�\u001c��\u0000\u0001��J��#�bc�|�\u0017%�\u001af���yy�{�i�H�\u0006��q!s\u001a!�\u0013c\u001b#ێ~m�\u0003\u000e0m��ςm�\f'�6F�\u001c+�\u0004\u000b�6�\u0004�\u001cB�\u0018��ٴ��j��ɱmOec\u000f��\u000f���c�\u001f�\rq�s\\}���B\u0011��02�L��j��\f7|�[L0{�#Ї㖖+\fc�Īt\u000bT:�8�T\u001bK��X\u0019�\u0005�cϔ��hc���\u0006�bP\u000bp΢���+PI�02?�)b\u0011�\u0005�T\r�kL�ܐ��'��#�\f\u000eOl�D��/�\r��+���.�\u001bTi�\u0013\u0001���i��\u001a�|��X|�\u001c\u0014��������~ѱp(�o\n�/�����\u0007�'\u0016�7I���$�X�\u0006�d\u0018>�\u0010�2��!��������SI�\u0000w j�I�d��)�1\n5#�~bƅ��T\u0019��H\u0019\u001c�9\f��\u001b\u001a�?\u0018W�0��h��1�JU�H�\b!��(a�$fbʼ�ؔ*`�21V��\"���2B\u0002?E\u000eS����4�\"��1z�tE�Q��S\u0018\u0016ii�D\u0006�dhXA�:�j�^�V#��d��\fYr�&Q�*[ ���\\����\u0003\u0007�\u0005�\u0006����Q(�T�F\f�G��\"'�\t�����D�x�-����_/'�^�\u0010�\u001c�\u0006h \r�\u001c7�\u0000u.>$\\�?��o��\u001b�gk^�u����L�|R��\u001b����\u00187���s�\u001b�h�L��\u0014�NDn���\u0010��g�2oF�;��3��\u0014����$\u0017�P�&\u0019��9?�P�*v��?˹�b�ϡ\\����\r�k&��\u0014rY\n���_\u0001)ɘ���j4�������e�e��\u001f\\��o.���\u000b�i������9�?5��_I��k��Rƿ{w������������t>~��,:>L���p\u0001\u001e\u0019�\u001a69\u001d�Y����J�@�#���F�A\u0003�\u0002�N�N�#$\u000b\u001fK\u0017�8\u0019\u00177>�t7{�\u001d��c#ȫO����\u001a87R\u0003D|¸\u0006o\u001f�@tl\u0018~\u0011I�\\�;Lb�LU�N_R�϶{%\u0010�\u0018\u0001��e����m4�Ɖ�-��:��8ئj��\u0002����\u001eG4���^6�3��fO���7R<~�J����\u0002�l�~C�\b�NgG��\u001a7�m���\"H\u0015�Qȱ[eq�\u000b�zS6E�7B�ΌF�f`\u0012ʓ(Ҭ�^�X%Y��A\n�R��pu������+$���\u0002X�\u0015�#B�D\u0005��q�-�%s8��\u0012\u0005I\u001a���\u0016����\u001b��y\u0004*��\u000ejCx\u0005\rqGx�\\��¾ȁL�r\u0019��\f2�'��\u001c��\n\u0005V�ڰH�@�sӐ�t��p\u001a)S�G=~�,\tFYnN�Q�C�i\u0012�)d��\u0013\u0019���>k\u0001�\u001f��Pf�\"U��|�J����m>rv\u0012��H\u0011\b��c�[��\u001b�\u0002dI�\f�ⷣ�yh���o}�K�R���\u0017c�W\u0000߶��0�}��?�\r�\u0007�\u001b\u0019\u0007��\u0011���@*��0_�\u0015�\u001d�\u0016�9�ߗ;�2C�L��\u000b�\u001b.\u001d��9�t��k\u000e_�{�~m�')]'�~|�x�@��_\u001eU��a`��w�Z׍\u001a9�Z�����\r\u0001���q��퓩\u000b��YܳL�\u0007�\b�S.�b*��w\u001d��`ٸ�\u0013\"F֮�i�_��\n�pm�9��֑ͥ�s\u0016�YQlz]q�\u0000�=�맓�\u0007\u0018^��8�]��+m\"����)��ݙ�<\n�|{��ձ�^�q�<�`�\u000b?�\u001f�������\u0018ªޘ���������u�#þ\u001e��Fڗ�_��^��\u0011�5\u0011/�wx����K��\u000b�8�����|�\u001fy��SQE������6��\u0001?\t�6E\\_��|U�\u001b�����ɞ9�.�Ҍ\u000eٽn�׭۹��>ze����U��v�\u0007�\u001d^�z�\u0003��o\u001fO\u0018�aP��-YG���e1\u000b[r�\u000b�\u0017�\n��b�}�\u0016���?B�\\�ד���Ш_Ƚ#�1t�\u0007�����P�\bl\u0007���<�n+���p�����#\u000e��%.\u001eS|'���D\u0017',PL�@y=�L.�@���ա�$29\b\u0004�-D�\\�\u0007z8:trf�\fH�p��8�2''�2��BG\u0007���[����8�j��\"w+��\u0005\u0012L\u0004=�qN.m\u001c�b�ۈZa�y���\n�J8>]���W�\u001bg�hӕd��t\u0006u\u0012��\u000b4���\u0015�a�;Q[���Ɲ�MA�*\f\u000f\u0013uk��\u001f  ... truncated
```

We can use `createObjectURL()` to trigger a download.

```
  const a = document.createElement('a')
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data)
  a.href = url
  a.download = name
  a.click()
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
```

Of course `createObjectURL()` expects an array or file so we should convert it to blob first.

```
  const blob = new Blob([data])
  const a = document.createElement('a')
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
  a.href = url
  a.download = name
  a.click()
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
```

This downloads a .txt file, however, which is not what we expect. We expect the behavior described above. Perhaps we should convert the data to Uint8 bytes before we attempt to download?

```
  var bytes = new Uint8Array(data)
  const blob = new Blob([bytes])
  const a = document.createElement('a')
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
  a.href = url
  a.download = name
  a.click()
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
```

This results in an empty text file. The impulse here I think is to assume we need to specify MIME type:

```
  const blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/octet-stream'})
  const a = document.createElement('a')
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
  a.href = url
  a.download = name
  a.click()
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
```

While this affects the type of file output, it doesn't change the result. In the case of `application/octet-stream`, it's still a txt file. `application/zip` will give us a zip that will not expand and throws an error.

Looks like I'm in need of a push in the right direction here.

Comment: try specifying the type in the Blob? like: `new Blob([bytes], { type: "application/octet-stream" } )`

Comment: @sciencefun Yes, I should have specified that I've tried that. I've updated the post to reflect that.

Comment: Shouldn't the `blob` be passed inside `createObjectURL` instead of data?

Comment: Yeah, that's a typo. Edited again.

Comment: If `data` is a string your file data is already corrupted, you need to get a blob or an array buffer from the source to be able to save the file properly.

Comment: @Musa I may be confusing terms here to be honest. I'm not sure if I'm getting a string or an array buffer from the source. I posted part of the source data value in my question. I lack the knowledge to determine whether that's a string or an array buffer. Would you be able to guide me here?

Comment: what is the input file type of your binary string? if the binary stream is from another zip file you can easily create a zip file. but it is not originated from a zip file, for example, your input file is a text file, and you need to use a JSZip-like library to convert it to a zip blob file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure about the input file type of your binary string.

###### recreating a File / Blob from the binary string.

```
const binaryString = `your binary string`
const bl = binaryString.length
const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(bl);
let chars = new Uint8Array(buffer);
for(let i=0; i<bl; i++)  chars[i] = binaryString.charCodeAt(i)

// here I've got the input file as a .exe file.
const file = new File([buffer], 'filename.exe', { type: "application/x-msdownload" });
```

###### creating a blob URL

```
const url = URL.createObjectURL(file)
```

###### download the file

```
const a = document.createElement('a')
a.href = url;
a.download = file.name;
a.click()
URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
```

e.g.

```js
const log = console.log;

const fileEl = document.getElementById("fileInput");

fileEl.addEventListener("change", () => {
  const file = fileEl.files[0];
  log(file);

  const filereader = new FileReader();
  filereader.readAsBinaryString(file);

  filereader.onload = (e) => {
    const binaryString = e.target.result;

    // log("your binary string: ", binaryString);

    const bl = binaryString.length;
    const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(bl);
    let chars = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    for (let i = 0; i < bl; i++) chars[i] = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);

    // application/x-zip-compressed - winrar archive
    // application/x-msdownload - windows executable files

    const file = new File([buffer], 'filename.exe', { type: "application/x-msdownload" });

    const url = URL.createObjectURL(file);

    const a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = url;
    a.download = file.name;
    a.click();
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  };
});
```

```html
  <input type="file" id="fileInput" />
```

Comment: I've also tried a similar strategy. The difficulty is that the input file is being retrieved from an api endpoint, not uploaded. The file behavior will change depending on the os/browser. On a Mac it will be a zip, but on PC it'll be an exe.  The file contained in the zip has the .app extension.

Comment: yeah, I've used that to simulate your API. can't you find the file type from your API?

Comment: It's really hard to find the file type from a binary string.

Comment: I just received this today, which is the library used to process the file in another implementation. I'm going to see how much help it is. https://smarthome.preview.support.com/consumer/content/scripts/connect-index.js

Comment: Turns out, `window.location = https://smarthome.preview.support.com/consumer/downloadNexus?id=${connectionCode}&sid=&sdid=&new_rang=false&is_brave=false&is_windows_eleven=false&mac_os_version=` is what we needed here. This is so specific to this use case that I don't even know if it's useful for anyone else.

Comment: Wow, is that all

Comment: I think Your question is a more generic one. So it will help another who is trying to convert binary strings to files.

Comment: I've accepted your answer because it's technically correct--just not in this instance.